# Call SelectMany with Expression.Call - wrong argument

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I want to go through relations by string.

I have a Person, a Work and Location that are connected Person N:1 Work and Work 1:N Location (each person can have 1 work and a work can have many locations).

Input for my method:

1. A list of persons (later the IQueryable of persons in EFCore)
2. The string "Work.Locations" to go from person to their work

So I have to call with Expressions:
 1. on the persons list a list.Select(x => x.Work)
 2. on that result a list.SelectMany(x => x.Locations)

I get an error when I make the Expression.Call on the SelectMany method (at the TODO)

```
        var selectMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().Single(a => a.Name == "SelectMany" && 
            a.GetGenericArguments().Length == 2 &&
            a.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(object), typeof(object)).GetParameters()[1].ParameterType == 
            typeof(Expression<Func<object, IEnumerable<object>>>));

        var par = Expression.Parameter(origType, "x");
        var propExpr = Expression.Property(par, property);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(propExpr, par);

        var firstGenType = reflectedType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

        //TODO: why do I get an exception here?
        selectExpression = Expression.Call(null,
            selectMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] {origType, firstGenType}),
            new Expression[] { queryable.Expression, lambda});
```

I get this exception:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Expression of type
>   'System.Func`2[GenericResourceLoading.Data.Work,System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[GenericResourceLoading.Data.Location]]'
>   cannot be used for parameter of type
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[GenericResourceLoading.Data.Work,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[GenericResourceLoading.Data.Location]]]'
>   of method
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[GenericResourceLoading.Data.Location]
>   SelectMany[Work,Location](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[GenericResourceLoading.Data.Work],
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[GenericResourceLoading.Data.Work,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[GenericResourceLoading.Data.Location]]])''

My full code looks like that:

```
    public void LoadGeneric(IQueryable<Person> queryable, string relations)
    {
        var splitted = relations.Split('.');
        var actualType = typeof(Person);

        IQueryable actual = queryable;
        foreach (var property in splitted)
        {
            actual = LoadSingleRelation(actual, ref actualType, property);
        }

        MethodInfo enumerableToListMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToList", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        var genericToListMethod = enumerableToListMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { actualType });

        var results = genericToListMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { actual });
    }

    private IQueryable LoadSingleRelation(IQueryable queryable, ref Type actualType, string property)
    {
        var origType = actualType;
        var prop = actualType.GetProperty(property, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        var reflectedType = prop.PropertyType;
        actualType = reflectedType;

        var isGenericCollection = reflectedType.IsGenericType && reflectedType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>);

        MethodCallExpression selectExpression;

        if (isGenericCollection)
        {
            var selectMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().Single(a => a.Name == "SelectMany" && 
                a.GetGenericArguments().Length == 2 &&
                a.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(object), typeof(object)).GetParameters()[1].ParameterType == 
                typeof(Expression<Func<object, IEnumerable<object>>>));

            var par = Expression.Parameter(origType, "x");
            var propExpr = Expression.Property(par, property);
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda(propExpr, par);

            var firstGenType = reflectedType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

            //TODO: why do I get an exception here?
            selectExpression = Expression.Call(null,
                selectMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] {origType, firstGenType}),
                new Expression[] { queryable.Expression, lambda});
        }
        else
        {
            var selectMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().Single(a => a.Name == "Select" && 
                a.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(object), typeof(object)).GetParameters()[1].ParameterType == 
                typeof(Expression<Func<object, object>>));

            var par = Expression.Parameter(origType, "x");
            var propExpr = Expression.Property(par, property);
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda(propExpr, par);

            selectExpression = Expression.Call(null,
                selectMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] {origType, reflectedType}),
                new Expression[] {queryable.Expression, lambda});
        }

        var result = Expression.Lambda(selectExpression).Compile().DynamicInvoke() as IQueryable;
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's failing because `SelectMany<TSource, TResult>` method expects

```
Expression<Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TResult>>>
```

while you are passing

```
Expression<Func<TSource, ICollection<TResult>>>
```

These are not the same and the later is not convertible to the former simply because `Expression<TDelegate>` is a *class*, and classes are invariant.

Taking your code, the expected lambda result type is like this:

```
var par = Expression.Parameter(origType, "x");
var propExpr = Expression.Property(par, property);
var firstGenType = reflectedType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
var resultType = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(firstGenType);
```

Now you can either use `Expression.Convert` to change (cast) the property type:

```
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Convert(propExpr, resultType), par);
```

or (my preferred) use another `Expression.Lambda` method overload with explicit delegate type (obtained via `Expression.GetFuncType`):

```
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(Expression.GetFuncType(par.Type, resultType), propExpr, par);
```

Either of these will solve your original issue.

Now before you get the next exception, the following line:

```
var genericToListMethod = enumerableToListMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { actualType });
```

is also incorrect (because when you pass "Work.Locations", the `actualType` will be `ICollection<Location>`, not `Location` which `ToList` expects), so it has to be changed to:

```
var genericToListMethod = enumerableToListMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { actual.ElementType });
```

In general you could remove `actualType` variable and always use `IQueryable.ElementType` for that purpose.

Finally as a bonus, there is no need to find manually the generic method definitions. `Expression.Call` has a special overload which allows you to easily "call" static generic (and not only) methods by name. For instance, the `SelectMany` "call" would be like this:

```
selectExpression = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable), nameof(Queryable.SelectMany), new [] { origType, firstGenType },
    queryable.Expression, lambda);
```

and calling `Select` is similar.

Also there is no need to create additional lambda expression, compile and dynamically invoke it in order to get the resulting `IQueryable`. The same can be achieved by using `IQueryProvider.CreateQuery` method:

```
//var result = Expression.Lambda(selectExpression).Compile().DynamicInvoke() as IQueryable;
var result = queryable.Provider.CreateQuery(selectExpression);
```

Comment: Thank you! That is a great solution!
But when I try to call the ToList of Enumerable it says me a similar problem that it could not be converted:`System.ArgumentException: 'Object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable´1[Entity.Models.Location]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable´1[System.Collections.Generic.ICollection´1[Entity.Models.Location]]'.'
`

Comment: I think I included that in the answer (because I got it during the test). It is the part where I replaced `actualType` with `actual.ElementType`.

Comment: Oh yes that's true! Now I understand that part :D

Answer (score 0):

You use your method with a type of `ICollection<T>`, but your expression takes a `IEnumerable<T>` as input. And `SelectMany()` takes a `IQueryable<T>` as input. Both `IQueryable<T>` and `ICollection<T>` are derived from `IEnumerable<T>`, but if you need a `IQueryable<T>` you cant give a `ICollection<T>`.

This would be the same as the following example:

```
class MyIEnumerable
{ }
class MyICollection : MyIEnumerable
{ }
class MyIQueryable : MyIEnumerable
{ }
private void MethodWithMyIQueryable(MyIQueryable someObj)
{ }

private void DoSth()
{
    //valid
    MethodWithMyIQueryable(new MyIQueryable());
    //invalid
    MethodWithMyIQueryable(new MyICollection());
}
```

They share the same inheritance from object, but still have no linear inheritance to each other.

Try casting/converting your `ICollection<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` and then give that as parameter.

Comment: I tried it with Expression.Convert but that doesn't work:
var converted = Expression.Convert(propExpr, enumerableType);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(converted, par);